# What is the difference between "vector<int> v[]" and "vector<vector<int>> v"

Tags: c++, vector

I do not know the difference between `vector<int> v[]` and `vector<vector<int>> v`

```
vector<int>v[] = {{ 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }};

v[0][0] = 4;
v[0][1] = 2;
v[0].push_back(4);

for (int i = 0; i < v[0].size(); i++)
    cout << v[0][i] << endl;

cout << v[1][0] << endl;
```

output : 4 2 4 2

```
vector<vector<int>> v = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };

v[0][0] = 4;
v[0][1] = 2;
v[0].push_back(4);

for (int i = 0; i < v[0].size(); i++)
    cout << v[0][i] << endl;

cout << v[1][0] << endl;
return 0;
```

output : 4 2 4 2

Is there a difference in memory or the creation process?

Comment: The former is an array of `vector`, the latter is a `vector` of `vector`. The former is fixed in size, though the vectors within are dynamic. The latter is dynamic for both the vectors within and the vector that contains them.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Aha!! Horizontal is variable, vertical is fixed. thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vector<int>v[] = {{ 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }};
```

This is an array of vector.

---

```
vector<vector<int>> v = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };
```

This is vector of vector.

---

> Is there a difference in memory or the creation process?

So of course, yes, there are differences in both memory and creation.

- The former is a fixed 2D-array of vector. Although the 2nd dimension (vector) can grow or shrink, the 1st dimension is not. It's similar to a [2 x Y] matrix.
- The latter is vector of vector. So both 1st and 2nd dimensions can change. So it  can be similar to [X x Y] matrix, where both X and Y can change at run time.